# facebook graph api get reference to "commented on" posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook Graph API to get references to special types of posts on my home page. When I use https://graph.facebook.com/me I see that I get all my posts except the ones I want, they have a special title that says " commented on a post from ." I guess this is by design, but I would like to get a reference to those posts. I understand they are not actually posts and that they are more like notifications telling me that my friend has commented on an actual post, but I would like to get a reference to that "Mr X commented on a post from December 11, 2013." post/notification.

If this is not possible, an alternative acceptable answer is that I would like to get a reference to all the posts that are very popular on my wall. Very popular being the posts that have thousands or hundreds of thousands of comments.

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's possible, depending on permissions. Look in the `link` field. You'll see something like `http://facebook.com/<FIRST_NUMBER>/posts/<SECOND_NUMBER>`. If you do another graph call to `<FIRST_NUMBER>_<SECOND_NUMBER>` you can get the other post if permissions all go through.

EDIT: This doesn't work about 75% of the time for me. So I just filter out those posts in my dataset.